# Where can I buy "all-in-one" sensors?

Tags: sensors

I am looking for all-in-one sensors that I can buy off the shelf.
All-In-One means that they should have BLE and Battery in the device itself!
I would be looking for Temperature, Humidity & Proximity sensors.

I only found [these](https://www.disruptive-technologies.com/solution/) from what seems to be a start-up but they are not available and it seems to be proprietary for only their IoT-Gateway and IoT-Platform.

Is there anything on the free market that I can buy, so I don't have to build my own sensors using an Arduino?
Or alternatively, what are the smallest possible sensors to build with integrated battery & bluetooth?

**EDIT**:

Alright. Am I right that those "all-in-one" sensors are just called "beacons" and therefor I didn't find them earlier?

**EDIT2**:

And what is the difference between the iBeacon/Eddystone protocols and BLE? I don't get it anymore. And why are those things Beacons and not sensors?

Comment: Sensors such as temperature, humidity, etc. are sensors in that they "sense" some measurable phenomena. Beacons are something different. There are different kinds but they all operate similarly. A beacon emits a signal of some kind such as radar beacons, radio beacons, light beacons, etc. See this write up about iBeacon and Eddystone which are different types of Bluetooth radio beacons https://kontakt.io/beacon-basics/ibeacon-and-eddystone/

Comment: Most smart phones have a selection of sensors built into the phone though some of the sensor aren't that accurate. There are also all in one weather stations if that is what you want. You could join Weather Underground which has suggests several kits. I would doubt that you would ever find a truly all in one solution since there are so many different types of sensors and it makes no commercial sense to bundle them all together. See this list for the Raspberry Pi for instance https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-sensors-overview-50-important-components/

Comment: Your question can't really b e answered, unless you define "all"

Comment: Yes. I think you guys are right. I have updated my question to better tell what I mean with "all-in-one". I am looking for sensors that have BLE and Energy onboard and I don't have to rebuild my own sensor with an Arduino + DHT22 + HC-05 + Battery Adapter for example.

Comment: https://thingsee.com has some kind of all-in-one solution. Needed data as a service.

Comment: I would recommend that you ask at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ , ***BUT*** you will have to know what you want to sense before you post - and "everything" will not be accetpable